Video metadata takes forever to load, can it be cached?
I organize a vast amount of videos (on Windows 11 using Windows Explorer or Directory Opus), and since these two can't be set to cache the metadata, I was wondering if Windows or a file system or something could be set to retain it? This would make every heavy operations (like sorting them all by resolution) lightning fast rather than taking hours and straining the HDD unnecessarily. I could build my own database, sure, but I'd really love the metadata to be available for Windows Explorer (and therefore Directory Opus too).

If you add the folder the videos are in, in your search indexer, wouldn't it then also index the meta data?

No. Takes just as long every time.

@JoepvanSteen I thought that's where file comments and are stored.

@Gantendo this is strictly for Windows or Directory Opus enabled metadata.
